# Android SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a Date column in sqlite database. With the help of cursor I am able to retrieve the values from that column. The Values are in this format, "YYYY-mm-dd". I want them to be converted to this format, "Mar 08 2013". How is this possible with SimpleDateFormat?

Can any one suggest please!!
 Any help will be Appreciated!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one quick solution:

```
String sourceDate = c.getString(<columnNumber>);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
Date formatted = null;
try {
    formatted = formatter.parse(sourceDate);
}
catch (ParseException ex) {
   Log.w("ParseError", ex.getMessage());
}
String formattedString = formatter.format(formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use DateUtils.
It contains a lot of static methods to help you format date, times, time deltas into a human-readable String.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html